# Как в IntelliJ IDEA создать Spring Project с template

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-mvc

Поставил IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, посмотрел несколько руководств по работе со Spring - везде, когда создается SpringMVC-проект, есть этап создания с шаблоном, где выбирается и сервер.
У меня же этот этап пропускается, и просто создается приложение, где и сервера нет, и папка src пустая. Почему так, разница в изданиях среды разработки?

Comment: Все сделал, все равно не дает шаблонов(

Answer (score 2):

File `--->` Settings `--->` Plugins `--->` поставить галочку на против плагина Spring.
В дальнейшем при создании проекта будет возможность выбрать Spring шаблон